# Rewrite URL in IIS7 .NET MVC

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, url, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite the url:

https://mydomain/phone-append

to

https://mydomain/Service/PhoneAppend

using the following rule:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Phone Append">
                <match url="phone-append" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/Services/Index"  appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

The rule works fine if the rewrite url is /Services but when I change it to /Services/PhoneAppend I get a page not found error. I've been pulling my hair out for a couple hours. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Failed Request Tracing to troubleshoot the failure: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/467/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules/

I cant see why it would not work, the rule above says that it will match (using Regular Expressions) any URL that contains phone-append on it, and rewrite to /Services/Index passing the query string.

If you use Failed Request TRacing you will see the details of the rewrite.

finally if you cant figure it out, URL Rewrite team answers a lot of questions at forums.iis.net